# How to compare a value with a list of dicts without using for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

Input:

```
value = "apple"
dict = [{'name':'apple','color':"red"},{'name':'orange','color':"orange"}]
```

Witout using the for loop like below, is it possible to compare and get the values?

Code I have done:

```
for i in dict:
   if i["name"] == value:
      print i
```

Comment: your loop is wrong, you have a list of dictionaries not a list of strings... what you named "name" is a dict object not a string

Comment: You have multiple items, so there's no escape from looping on them. Even if you don't write a loop "explicitly", something like `filter(lambda d: d['name'] == 'apple', dict)` will still iterate on the list.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: edited@daveoncode

Comment: It slows down the server speed and all@wwii

Comment: Maroun post it as an answer, It works@Maroun

Comment: How do you return without a list@Maroun

Answer (score 0):

You do have multiple dicts in a list, not just one.
Therefore you must go through all items in your list.

```
for d in dict: # dict is actually a list, but I am using your var name
   if value in d.values():
       print(value)
```

Comment: I want it without a loop@Alexander

Comment: Is the problem that you do not want to "look" at every item in the list or is your problem the `for` loop and e.g. a `while` loop would work?